# How do I maintain sessions between Thread Groups in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies

I have 5 thread groups (Ultimate Thread Group) in JMeter. When I run the entire test, the samples in the first thread group work fine, those in the second thread group invoke the web sites timeout page, but when the same samples (in the second thread group) are put in the first thread group and the test run, they work fine and do not invoke the timeout page. I realise that I need to pass the session from the first thread group to the other thread groups, please how do I do this?

The following is the cookie data:-

[image]

The following are the thread groups:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass data between different Thread Groups most probably your test is badly designed.

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) must represent a real user with all its stuff (Cookies, Cache, Headers, think times, etc). If these 5 business actions are a part of a single used workflow - they need to be put under the same thread group.

Use different thread groups to represent different groups of business users.

---

If you really need to pass cookies between thread groups it can be done using [JSR223 Scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)